# error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: glibc

I was debugging an error on my system (debian linux) and part of that I renamed the `libc.so.6` file to something else.

```
$ sudo mv libc.so.6 libc-2.28.so.6
```

Now none of my bash commands will work.

```
$ ls
ls: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
$ sudo mv libc-2.28.so.6 libc.so.6
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this please?

The file exists but I can't rename it back:

```
$ ./libc-2.28.so.6
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+deb10u2) stable release version 2.28.
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 8.3.0.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Your packages are all EOL in Ubuntu systems*

Comment: If your system includes the statically-linked `busybox`, you may be able to use that - see for example [After accidentally renaming /usr, how do I rename it back?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432003/65304)